# How to fix backspaces sent via Telnet to Inputstream in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, chat, inputstream, telnet

On my Java Chatserver users can change their username by using backspaces infront of their message.

I am currently coding a chat-server and client in Java. It works really well but I have the annoying 'bug', that the users can send messages without their username by using backspaces infront of their messages because telnet or the used BufferedReader-InputStream is saving backspaces in the message-string.

I tried to replace backspaces which made it impossible for users to change spelling mistakes.

I don't know what I should try next.

Example:
`Test>[10 backspaces]This is a test.`
The others are getting the message `This is a test.` but the actual message should be `Test:This is a test.`

Comment: Can you try to do `String.trim()` on the message? It will remove leading and trailing whitespace (if I am not mistaken including backspace and anything with Ascii code less than `0x20`)

Comment: Where does the displayed "Test:" prefix come from?  Client or server?   If the server, and therefore you have the message with just leading backspaces (not including the prefix you don't want to lose), the above suggestion to trim whitespace is a good one.

Comment: The prefix gets applied from the Server. I try it with trimming

It is working. Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code fixed my issue partly:

```
while (input.contains("\b")) input = input.replaceAll("^\b+|[^\b]\b", "");
```